# PHP warning on Mac mini running Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: php, osx-yosemite

When I type php -v in the terminal on my mac mini I get the following error message:

> "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_pgsql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_pgsql.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pgsql.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP 5.5.29 (cli) (built: Sep 
>   6 2015 20:20:34)  Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies"

To update PHP I run the following:
`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0`
and it appears like it install successfully; however, when I check the version php -v; I keep getting the same error message.  I'd appreciate some assistance with this issue.  Thanks

Comment: Its not a duplicate.  I'm not tryig to use postgres..Im using MySQL.  Also, these are dated questions.  Can someone please help me with this issue?  Thanks

Comment: Reinstall PHP. I'd recommend doing it via Homebrew. http://brew.sh/ I don't know what `http://php-osx.liip.ch/` is but their serving a `.sh` via unencrypted HTTP points pretty comfortably to amateur hour.

Comment: brew.sh?  care to give more details?

Comment: Click the link. Homebrew is a widely used, developer oriented package manager for OSX. Tutorials for installing PHP with Homebrew are readily available.

Comment: I have homebrew installed already

Comment: OK, so install PHP using it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer ceejayoz.  I didn't see your comment initially.  This did the trick. https://gist.github.com/bobthecow/85ad6dfb594d9215b42b